# AOL , Yahoo, Hotmail Contact Api Not Working

Tags: asp.net, google-contacts-api, yahoo-api, hotmail

In a website I want user to invite their friends from their google,aol,yahoo,hotmail contact by including them here.

I got the functionality for gmail, But cannot find anything related to AOL i think it is removed from their official website ,For Msn also there is problem . I think they are not allowing their users to import the contacts . In case of yahoo there are some errors occuring

```
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
length: 6
stack trace: at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at test_oauth_test.RetriveContacts()
status: ProtocolError
Status Code: (404) NotFound
Status Description: Not Found on Accelerator
source: System
headers: 0: close
headers: 1: en
headers: 2: 1865
headers: 3: no-store
headers: 4: text/html
headers: 5: Tue, 31 Mar 2015 10:23:44 GMT
headers: 6: ATS
headers: 7: http/1.1 r13.ycpi.dcb.yahoo.net (ApacheTrafficServer [c s f ])
```

I am also wondering if there is code available with which i can provide a button to user when user click on it Gmail Authentication popup shows then after that contacts are shown

Comment: For Importing Gmail COntacts I am using code in this link - http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Import-Contacts-from-Google-Gmail-Account-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

that popup the windows for authentication but it only works at localhost when deployed to online it gives at following line -


 using ASPSnippets.GoogleAPI; 

and says namespace aspsnippets does not exist

Comment: **Microsoft** changed all contacts importing to Outlook.com and you need to import them using OAuth2. I just answered a question about that today [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355295/how-to-import-contacts-from-hotmail/29368298#29368298).

For **AOL**, you'll find a documentation for OAuth2, but the registration is not public.

Comment: actually links for AOL developer page and documentation is removed by them

Comment: https://identity.aol.com/documentation/start/oauth2/